# Confused about Azure VM Creation

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

So I am a little bit confused about the Azure feature to create virtual machines(i.e VMRoles).

When I do a quick create via the managment portal, I am not asked to specify nor a hosted service nor a storage account. After I click 'create' I see that a storage account is generated for me automatically with some unique name, but I don't see the same for a hosted service. Is a hosted service not needed to create a VM?

The thing that is confusing is that it seems like every other method for creating a VM does require me to specify a hosted service (Azure PowerShell, REST API). And indeed after I create the VM using one of these methods I see my VM inside the hosted service...

Anyone can explain this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please do not confuse [Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/virtual-machines/) (IaaS, stateful) with [Windows Azure VMRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433107.aspx) (PaaS, stateless).

As for creation - the process behind the portal is automated. For me, I have a separate Cloud Service for each Virtual Machine I've created (along with the auto generated storage account). However as all operations are asyc, and I also guess the Microsoft teams are using some kind of CQRS pattern behind the portal, it might take some time for all the components behind a Virtual Machine to appear. While the API strictly requires everything to be ready set, before you actually create the Virtual Machine. My guess is that soon you will also see a cloud service created for your VM (it usually is with the name of the Virtual Machine you created). Also, if you have noticed, the public URI for accessing your Virtual Machine (be it RDP or SSH) has the format of [your_vm_name].cloudapp.net - so this is a Cloud Service (formerly known as Hosted Service).

Answer (score 0):

First of all Windows Azure Virtual Machines and VM Role are two separate things. Based on what  you have explained it seems you are trying to create a Windows Azure Virtual Machine so I will explain you in short how it works:

Very first: In order to create a Windows Azure Virtual Machine you need a VHD which has OS Image. You can use one from Gallery or you can upload one by yourself to your specific Blob Azure Storage.

When you use Quick create or create the process is exactly same in the background however during quick create lots of settings is already predefined as will quick create you will only get Windows OS VHD to choose. In both cases a storage account is used to copy the OS VHD (if it is not part of your OS image collection). In most of the cases a previously created storage account is used, so you may think in was not created but in fact the storage account was used to copy the VHD from repo. This may not be the case if you create a VM from an image which is already in your OS VHD collection.

With quick create the DNS name you set is become the VM name but with create you have option to create a different DNS name for your application but they needed in both cases. In any case the DNS name will bind to your VM, the same DNS name will distinguish your VM from others and a must to configure for any VM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the cloud service is not surfaced for a single quick-create Virtual Machine. This is to make Virtual Machines as easy to use as possible. The cloud service would be created and be displayed on the portal were a second virtual machine to be added to the cloud service.